# If not logged in redirect to php page not working

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a login page in `PHP` just done for testing, I know my code is not secure.

I did below code to get some data from table and display in table:

```
session_start();
include("config.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['email']) && $_SESSION['email'] == true){
    $user_email=$_SESSION['email'];

    $check_user="select * from admin WHERE user_email='$user_email'";

    $run=mysqli_query($link,$check_user);

    while($row = $run->fetch_assoc()){

        $_SESSION['access']=$row['access'];
        $_SESSION['name']=$row['user_name'];

    }
}
```

Till here it's working properly, when I login into my page using following code for login page:

```
session_start();
include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $user_email=$_POST['email'];
    $user_pass=$_POST['pass'];

    $check_user="select * from admin WHERE user_email='$user_email'AND user_pass='$user_pass'";

    $run=mysqli_query($link,$check_user);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0){

        $_SESSION['email']=$user_email;

        $_SESSION['access']=$result['access'];

        //here session is used and value of $user_email store in $_SESSION.
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";
    }else{
    echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
    }
}
```

But when I'm trying to add the following code for redirecting user if not logged in, even if I login I'm redirected to login page again and again.

The mistake is with the below code:

```
session_start();
include("config.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['email']) && $_SESSION['email'] == true){
    $user_email=$_SESSION['email'];

    $check_user="select * from admin WHERE user_email='$user_email'";

    $run=mysqli_query($link,$check_user);

    while($row = $run->fetch_assoc()){

        $_SESSION['access']=$row['access'];
        $_SESSION['name']=$row['user_name'];
    }
}

//if login in session is not set
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){ 
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

I am new to php, can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You set the value for `$_SESSION['access']` and `$_SESSION['name']` if login successfully but you check login against `$_SESSION['login']`

Comment: I don't see where you are setting $_SESSION["login"], are you setting it somewhere else?

Comment: @catcon i didnt understand coz i am new to this can you please help me with my code as an answer

Comment: @John.M i didnt set session login anywhere, i am doing coding with the help of google, so there is alot of mistakes from my side

Comment: @TEIA2019 :  [Try this link](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-login-system.php)

Comment: You should click through the link provided above, there's a lot of good info in there that you must include in your login script.

Comment: @TEIA2019 - Please also read up on how to prevent sql injection here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Answer (score -3):

```
<?php
session_start();
include("config.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
{
$user_email=$_SESSION['email'];
$check_user="select * from admin WHERE user_email='$user_email'";

$run=mysqli_query($link,$check_user);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run))
{
$_SESSION['access']=$row['access'];
$_SESSION['name']=$row['user_name'];
$_SESSION['login']=$row['user_login'];

}

}

if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){ //if login in session is not set
    header("Location: login.php");}
?>
```

**3 code**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass']))
{
$user_email=$_POST['email'];
$user_pass=$_POST['pass'];

$check_user="select * from admin WHERE user_email='$user_email' AND user_pass='$user_pass'";

$run=mysqli_query($link,$check_user);

if(mysqli_num_rows($run)>0)
{

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
$_SESSION['email']=$user_email;

$_SESSION['access']=$result['access'];
}

//here session is used and value of $user_email store in $_SESSION.
echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";

}
else
{
echo "<script>alert('Email or password is incorrect!')</script>";
}
}?>
```

**2 code**

```
    <?php
session_start();
     include("config.php");

    if(isset($_SESSION['email']))
    {
    $user_email=$_SESSION['email'];

    $check_user="select * from admin WHERE user_email='$user_email'";

    $run=mysqli_query($link,$check_user);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run))
    {
    $_SESSION['access']=$row['access'];
    $_SESSION['name']=$row['user_name'];
    }

    }
     ?>
```

**1 code**

Comment: No no no, you're recommending that the OP pass posted data directly into the query, his code has a number of issues, reusing it in this answer is bad advice.

Comment: its still not working, redirecting me to login page again and again

Comment: on code 3, remember $ _SESSION ['login'] = $ row ['user_login']; on
$ _SESSION ['login'] = $ row ['access']; If it works, check it out.

Comment: @MubinjonMuinov can you please tell me from this value is coming $_SESSION['login']=$row['user_login'];

Comment: one more thing, do you have data on the admin table? There is an email check, but if there is no data on the table or there is no similar data, you will be redirected to the "login.php"

Comment: @TEIA2019  You on the 3 code check on $ _SESSION ['login'] but on your code I don’t where I get the $ _SESSION ['login'] value on myself and so I added this code to check if the code works.

Comment: @MubinjonMuinov there is no $row['user_login']; set in my code, i did using your changes its not working

Comment: then after the code $ run = mysqli_query ($ link, $ check_user); on code 3 write echo mysqli_num_rows($run); and see how many rows it returns.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code - what **exactly** have you changed and why? Keep in mind that such an explanation helps others to understand your code